# tagForChildDirectedTreatment(boolean) deprecated

Tags: java, android-studio, admob

I am trying to update library 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads' from version 17.2.0 to 18.1.1. I got a warning that the method builder.tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true) was deprecated.

In documentation (https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder) it is said that setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(int) should be used instead. But I could not find any examples of how to use it. Documentation (https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting) was not updated. They still use deprecated tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true). Can somebody help me with that?

Here is my code:

```
private void loadAds() {
    MobileAds.initialize(this, getString(R.string.adMobAppId));
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.adMobUnitId));
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putBoolean("is_designed_for_families", true);
    AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras);
    builder.tagForChildDirectedTreatment(true);
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(builder.build());
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {

            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084706/should-we-first-call-mobileads-setrequestconfiguration-or-mobileads-initialize

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I had the same problem and I couldn't find any answer I wrote it, but I don't know whether it's right or not

here is my code

```
RequestConfiguration conf= new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_TRUE).build();

    MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(conf);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: Should we call `initialize` first or `setRequestConfiguration` first? Do you have any documentation on this?

Comment: as the Admob documentation said you should set it before initializing.

Comment: @AfshinIzadi do you have any link to that documentation?

Comment: @radus14 https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/quick-start#initialize_the_sdk

Comment: for new update use 

RequestConfiguration.TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_TRUE

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code :

```java
MobileAds.initialize(this, id);
RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration = MobileAds.getRequestConfiguration().toBuilder()
        .setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_TRUE)
        .build();
```

Comment: please indent your code properly and do add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, we need to initialize the SDK:

```java
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          MobileAds.initialize (this, id);
```

2. Next, Child-directed setting:

```java
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          MobileAds.initialize (this, id);
          RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration = MobileAds.getRequestConfiguration (). toBuilder () //case sensitive!
             .setTagForChildDirectedTreatment (TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_TRUE)
             .build ();
```

3. Create banner ads

```java
    private void loadBannerAds()
    {
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putBoolean("is_designed_for_families", true);
            AdView mAdView = findViewById (R.id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder ()
               .addNetworkExtrasBundle (AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
               .build ();
            mAdView.loadAd (adRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using in Kotlin.

```
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView)
    MobileAds.initialize (this)
    val conf = RequestConfiguration.Builder()
        .setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_TRUE).build()
    MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(conf)
  
    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's done as such (this is in Xamarin using C#):

```
MobileAds.RequestConfiguration =
    new RequestConfiguration
        .Builder()
        .SetTagForChildDirectedTreatment(RequestConfiguration.TagForChildDirectedTreatmentTrue)
        .SetMaxAdContentRating(RequestConfiguration.MaxAdContentRatingG)
#if DEBUG
        .SetTestDeviceIds(new[] { "..." })
#endif
        .Build();
```