# Should we first call MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration or MobileAds.initialize?

Tags: android, admob

There isn't much documentation on this. I was wondering, should we first call

```
RequestConfiguration conf= new RequestConfiguration.Builder()
        .setMaxAdContentRating(
                MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_T)
        .build();

MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(conf);
MobileAds.initialize(context, APP_ID);
```

Or

```
MobileAds.initialize(context, APP_ID);
RequestConfiguration conf= new RequestConfiguration.Builder()
        .setMaxAdContentRating(
                MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_T)
        .build();

MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(conf);
```

---

In https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Although Google recommend calling `MobileAds.initialize` as early as possible

> Before loading ads, have your app initialize the Mobile Ads SDK by
>   calling MobileAds.initialize() which initializes the SDK and calls
>   back a completion listener once initialization is complete (or after a
>   30-second timeout). This needs to be done only once, ideally at app
>   launch.

They also mention "request-specific flags" need to be set before `MobileAds.initialize`.

> Warning: Ads may be preloaded by the Mobile Ads SDK or mediation
>   partner SDKs upon calling MobileAds.initialize(). If you need to
>   obtain consent from users in the European Economic Area (EEA), set any
>   request-specific flags (such as tagForChildDirectedTreatment or
>   tag_for_under_age_of_consent), or otherwise take action before loading
>   ads, ensure you do so before initializing the Mobile Ads SDK.

So, not super clear on which should be called first.

Comment: You should be doing this inside your  Application class!

Comment: The best place is to put it in application class.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to Google Developer support, the following is the right way to do

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/android/17oVu0sABjs

```
RequestConfiguration conf= new RequestConfiguration.Builder()
        .setMaxAdContentRating(
                MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_T)
        .build();

MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(conf);
MobileAds.initialize(context, APP_ID);
```

Answer (score -1):

according to the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)

> Before loading ads, have your app initialize the Mobile Ads SDK by calling `MobileAds.initialize()` which initializes the SDK and calls back a completion listener once initialization is complete (or after a 30-second timeout). This needs to be done only once, ideally at app launch.

So , you should initialize `MobileAds` first ,look at the example [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner) form the official documentation :

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Comment: How about using together with `RequestConfiguration.Builder`? There isn't much sample with `MobileAds.initialize`.

Comment: builder is used to build the Ad request to be shown on the adview , and before that you should initialize your mobileAds

Comment: If you look at the same page, "request-specific flags" need to be called before "MobileAds.initialize". "tagForChildDirectedTreatment " is provided in `RequestConfiguration`

Comment: yeah but they just ask to add flags that will be recognized in RequestConfiguration

Comment: yeah but they just ask to add flags that will be recognized in RequestConfiguration

Answer (score -1):

It's done as such:

```
MobileAds.RequestConfiguration =
    new RequestConfiguration
        .Builder()
        .SetTagForChildDirectedTreatment(RequestConfiguration.TagForChildDirectedTreatmentTrue)
        .SetMaxAdContentRating(RequestConfiguration.MaxAdContentRatingG)
#if DEBUG
        .SetTestDeviceIds(new[] { "..." })
#endif
        .Build();
```